What does "Mas que nada" mean and how does that derive from the individual words?
The recent death of Sérgio Mendes gave rise to an obituary in a UK paper which mentioned, among other things his performance of the song Mas que Nada.
I am struggling to disentangle that title. Initially I thought mas might be a misprint for mais but that is clearly not the case. I know that mas is roughly equivalent to the English but and I know what the other two words mean in isolation but how does it all fit together?

Mas que nada
Sai da minha frente
Que eu quero passar
Pois o samba está animado
O que eu quero é sambar

@Lambie ah that helps. I did not find the lyrics on-line so I suspected there was some copyright issue. Or it is just that I am hopeless at searching especially in Portuguese.

Lyrics in Portuguese is Letra, so  your search would be: Letra + mas que nada site:.br

I always thought it was mais que nada.  Then again, I never checked whether it's mas or mais.


A música 'Mas Que Nada', composta e interpretada por Jorge Ben Jor, é
um clássico da música brasileira que exalta a alegria e a irreverência
do samba. A expressão 'Mas que nada' é uma maneira informal e
tipicamente brasileira de desdenhar obstáculos e problemas, sugerindo
que nada deve impedir o prazer e a celebração da vida.

mas que nada
It boils down to "no way" [today] or "how silly" or "Bosh". And then a speaker will go on to explain themselves.
Bear in mind it is a spoken discourse expression used to disagree with what someone else has just said. The but (mas)  is just "but" in Portuguese but would not work in English in similar contexts. Often, it would just be "que nada", that is,  "no way".
So, THIS:
João: Essa é a melhor festa do ano. Sempre boa.
Marco: Mas, que nada, cara. A melhor festa é sempre a do Jorge.
COULD BE EXPRESSED AS:
João: Essa é a melhor festa do ano. Sempre boa.
Marco: Que nada, cara. A melhor festa é sempre a do Jorge.
Both those would be:
No way, man. The best party of the year is always Jorge's. Putting in the "but" links it to what was being said earlier.
In terms of the song, it's as if the author is rejecting in advance any discourse (speech) that would have come before it to deny what he says about how he feels about samba. Joyful, happy, ready to dance.
It is written as mas que nada but for the meaning, even in Portuguese, there is a pause: Mas, que nada!
First verse:
Mas que nada [No way: (what you said)]
Sai da minha frente [Get out of my way]
Que eu quero passar [I want to get by you]
Pois o samba está animado [The samba is lively]
O que eu quero é sambar  [What I want is to dance samba]
That is only an explanatory translation.
